# How do I print an activity?

Tags: activities

Civi used to have an option to print an activity and it would print the details of the activity. I'm in need of this and can't figure out how to print an activity now. Would be really nice if there was a print button at the bottom when viewing an activity.

What's the best way to get a nice print of an activity? We use an activity to record our meeting minutes and need to print them out to keep a hard copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it's a missing feature. I've [created a patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5927) which adds a print button to the dialog titlebar, hopefully this will make it into the 4.6.4 release.

[image]

For more details see https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16585

Answer (score 6):

I think you're referring to the fact that viewing an activity now happens in a pop-up window, and that window is missing a print button.

I think this is probably an oversight and would be nice to fix. In the meantime here is a workaround:

- On the list of activities, instead of clicking on the "View" button, right-click it and select "Open in a new tab."
- This will display the activity in full-screen mode so the print button will be available.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, but a bit overkill, there is a setting which turns off popup forms:

`Enable Popup Forms` at `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences` ( civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display )

That seems to cover this use case, and also removes the frustrations I find with not having the URL in sight when the pop up is working.

Comment: This seems a bit heavy-handed to me. Disabling popups makes the interface a lot less dynamic. FYI my patch above helps a bit with url visibility, hovering over the print button will show the url of the popup :)

Comment: I don't disagree that it was a bit overkill. But thought it was a valid solution to offer and useful to know it is a UI setting. Appreciate your patch - seems like best outcome for this.